# Is ++ atomic for std::atomic<int>

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic, stdatomic

Acording to one Channel 9 E2E video(with Herb Sutter in it) in c++0x if number is `atomic<int>`
`number++` is atomic. Can somebody confirm that is how it is in the final C++11 standard(lets pretend that it is finalized :)).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The standard *is* finalised, and every operation on all the standard integral specialisations of `atomic<T>` is atomic.

This doesn't mean all **expressions** involving standard integral `atomic<T>` are atomic.

```
number = number * 2;
```

is two operations:

```
temporary = number * 2;
number = temporary;
```

Each of them is atomic, but together they are not. This is what transactions/critical sections are for.

Comment: so number=number*2; and number=number+47; are also atomic?

Comment: Every operation that is *defined* for `atomic<T>` is atomic, like `number *= 2;` and `number += 47;`.

Comment: number=number*2 is *two* operations. *Each* of them is atomic, but together they are not. This is what "transactions" are for.

Comment: great answer, but could you also explain if x=a.load(); is same as x=a; //x is not atomic, a is

Comment: They are the same only provided that they don't interact with any other fetches/assignments. See [the example here in page 4](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/misc_slides/c++mm.pdf)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl (and future readers): Implicit conversion of `a` to `x`'s type will involve `a.load()`.  e.g. if you have `int x`, then `x = a` will involve conversion from `std::atomic<int> a` to `int`, via `operator T`. (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_T).  `a.load()` is atomic.  Nothing about the `x = ...` part is atomic for non-atomic `x`, so you need to ensure thread-safety a different way (typically by making `int x` a local variable that's not shared).

Comment: There's no way to do a single operation that atomically copies between two separate objects (because HW can't, except for a few rare CPUs, like some m68k having DCAS aka CAS2: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_compare-and-swap)

Comment: *This is what transactions/critical sections are for* - or CAS retry loops.  You can emulate any atomic RMW on a single object using `compare_exchange_weak`, including atomic left-shift (although some CPUs have that in hardware), or atomic multiply, atomic clear-lowest-set-bit (`tmp &= tmp - 1`) or whatever.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. `atomic<int> operator++` uses `atomic<int>::fetch_add` which is an atomic operation.

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf p. 1127